# What is the length of the shorter trisector of the right angle in a $3$-$4$-$5$ triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles

> What is the length of the shorter trisector of the right angle in a $3$-$4$-$5$ triangle?

I found this question in a local question paper, and I am unable to solve it. I applied Cosine formula, but I didn't got an elegant solution to it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The Sine Law should work fairly quickly.

Comment: And if you draw the triangle it's clear that you want the triangle with angle $\frac{\pi}{3}$ and $\arcsin\frac{3}{5}$.

Comment: The area of the right triangle is the sum of the areas of the sub-triangles created by the trisector.

Comment: For the shorter trisector I got $\dfrac{8(4\sqrt{3}-3)}{13}$ and for the longer I got  $\dfrac{24(3\sqrt{3}-4)}{11}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

$$\begin{align}
|\triangle ABC| &\;=\; |\triangle BDC| + |\triangle ADC| \\[6pt]
\implies \qquad \frac{1}{2}\,a b &\;=\; \frac{1}{2}\,a d \sin 30^\circ \;+\; \frac{1}{2}\,b d \sin 60^\circ \\[6pt]
\implies \qquad \frac{1}{2}\,a b &\;=\; \frac{1}{2}\,a d\cdot\frac{1}{2}  \;+\; \frac{1}{2}\,b d\cdot\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\[8pt]
\implies \qquad 2 a b &\;=\; d\left(\; a + b \sqrt{3} \;\right) \\[6pt]
\implies \qquad d &\;=\; \frac{2a b}{a + b\sqrt{3}}
\end{align}$$